# Using python, GTK+3, Vte libs. How to change the font size of a terminal?

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, gtk, font-size, vte

I made a program which shows four terminals in one window, but the font size is way too big. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python shells.py

from gi.repository import Gtk, Vte, Gdk
from gi.repository import GLib
import os

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="shells")
        self.resize(1000, 1000)

        table = Gtk.Table(2, 2, True)
        self.add(table)

        palette = [Gdk.color_parse('red')] * 16
        terminal1 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal2 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal3 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal4 = Vte.Terminal()

        scrolledwindow1 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow1.add(terminal1)

        scrolledwindow2 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow2.add(terminal2)

        scrolledwindow3 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow3.add(terminal3)

        scrolledwindow4 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow4.add(terminal4)

        terminal1.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin  /sh"], 
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)
        terminal2.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"],
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)
        terminal3.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"],
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)
        terminal4.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"],
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)

        terminal1.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('red'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)
        terminal2.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('green'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)
        terminal3.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('yellow'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)
        terminal4.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('blue'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)

        table.attach(scrolledwindow1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(scrolledwindow2, 1, 2, 0, 1)
        table.attach(scrolledwindow3, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(scrolledwindow4, 1, 2, 1, 2)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

According to the documentation [Vte set_font](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.26/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-set-font-full) I used:

```
import pango
font = pango.FontDescription()
terminal1.set_font(font)
```

And I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute '__info__'
```

The example is from a stack overflow question:
[how to enable transparency in vte.Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686510/how-to-enable-transparency-in-vte-terminal)

Then I used, according to this [Vte 'decrease-font-size' signal](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.26/VteTerminal.html#VteTerminal-decrease-font-size) :

```
terminal1.connect('decrease-font-size', function, data)
def function():
    print "press crtl -to decrease font-size"
```

Nothing happens with this one. And the rest also don't work.
I also noticed that I can't really change the size of one terminal using:

```
terminal1.set_size(30, 29)
```

Seems to change nothing.

For these examples I used for the sake of simplicity only terminal1.
Also one weird thing is that, when I do the "clear" command, it seems to rearrange itself and the font size becomes bigger.
I apologize for weird English. It's not my native language, but I'll try my best. When it comes to programming, I have only experience with python and associated libraries or modules. I'm using a Linux Debian version as OS.

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the `realize` signal of the `Vte.Terminal` as only then the `Pango.FontDescription()` is created, then `get_font()` on the terminal and `set_size()` on the `Pango.FontDescription()` returned by that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import os

from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Pango
from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Vte


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="shells")
        self.resize(1000, 1000)

        table = Gtk.Table(2, 2, True)
        self.add(table)

        palette = [Gdk.color_parse('red')] * 16
        terminal1 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal1.connect('realize', self.on_realize_terminal)
        terminal2 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal2.connect('realize', self.on_realize_terminal)
        terminal3 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal3.connect('realize', self.on_realize_terminal)
        terminal4 = Vte.Terminal()
        terminal4.connect('realize', self.on_realize_terminal)

        scrolledwindow1 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow1.add(terminal1)

        scrolledwindow2 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow2.add(terminal2)

        scrolledwindow3 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow3.add(terminal3)

        scrolledwindow4 = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow4.add(terminal4)

        terminal1.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"], 
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)
        terminal2.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"],
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)
        terminal3.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"],
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)
        terminal4.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/sh"],
                                   [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)

        terminal1.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('red'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)
        terminal2.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('green'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)
        terminal3.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('yellow'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)
        terminal4.set_colors(Gdk.color_parse('blue'), Gdk.color_parse('black'), palette)

        table.attach(scrolledwindow1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(scrolledwindow2, 1, 2, 0, 1)
        table.attach(scrolledwindow3, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(scrolledwindow4, 1, 2, 1, 2)

    def on_realize_terminal(self, terminal):
        font = terminal.get_font()
        font.set_size(16 * Pango.SCALE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MainWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Sry, but it doesn't work. Also it works with his guy's code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686510/how-to-enable-transparency-in-vte-terminal And he doesn't need a realize signal. Maybe everything is somehow broken because of the bad layout and the four terminals at the same time?